# Adding finished tweenlite to a timeline using deferred promise (Greensock)

Tags: javascript, jquery, tween, gsap

We can add multiple tweens to a timeline, like what is explained in this post: https://ihatetomatoes.net/greensock-timelinelite-tutorial/

But how can we add a tween to a timeline only when it is complete? I am asking this is because my project uses tweenLite to create a canvas animation:

```
       var tween = TweenLite.to(
            { currentTime: 0 },
            300,
            {
                currentTime:300,
                onUpdate: drawFunction,
                onComplete: endFunction
            }
        );
```

I am thinking of putting a deferred object and resolve it in my endFunction. But how can I get it back from `onComplete` and add the tween to the timeline? Any suggestion?

Comment: Sounds like a perfect use case for timeline.

Comment: @FrankerZ thanks...hope this isn't sarcastic...:X

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Why can't you just add multiple tweens simultaneously to the timeline? What's the reasoning for trying to add a tween on the onComplete function? When it's complete, it will move to the next item on the timeline anyway?

Answer (score 0):

First, Instead of TweenLite, please use TimelineLite.

Second, onComplete is a bit buggy. You should try calling a function in your timeline. The function will be called only after the previous tween is complete.

Third, You can also change the position of your tweens using the position parameters for advanced control. More details here : https://greensock.com/position-parameter

Code to create a timeline and call a code inside the timeline:

```
function myFunction(num) {
  console.log(num)
}

var tl = new TimelineMax();

tl.from($box, 1, {y: '-=40', autoAlpha: 0, ease:Power4.easeInOut}) // no comma or semi-colon
  .from($box2, 1, {y: '-=40', autoAlpha: 0, ease:Power4.easeInOut}) // no comma or semi-colon
  .from($box3, 1, {y: '-=40', autoAlpha: 0, ease:Power4.easeInOut}); // semi-colon after last tween
  .call(myFunction, ['1'])
```